# C# Math Problem - Rotational mapping?

Tags: c#, math

I am really in the deep end on what the heck I am doing.. all I know is what I need to get done.. how to get there.. i'm not sure.

*Edit to make clearer: We are dealing with two rotational values here that are increasing/decreasing at the same speed and are both shifted off by 1/2PI.

Start point/End point 1 is 2PI and PI1/2

Start point/End point 2 is 1/2PI and PI

I need to create an equation that maps rotational value 2 to rotational value 1 such that any value in that rotational section will give me the value of the other rotational object.   Example: rot 2 at 1/2PI (insert math here) = 2PI (the value at rot 1)

I'm sorry if this is a terribly easy question and i'm just stupid, but I honestly have no idea how to solve it.

Thanks.

Comment: question is not clear , add more details

Comment: What do you mean by "lines". And why do you have "lines" in quotes? What do you mean by "point" when you say `2 * pi`? Points in the Cartesian plane have two coordinates. Do you mean the point on the unit circle with angle `2 * pi`? If so, then by "lines" do you mean arcs along the unit circle? Then you say "I need [...] an equation that maps line 2 to line 1 such that any value along that line will give me the value of the other line." What do you mean "the value"? There are lots of ways to map one set to another; which map specifically are you looking for?

Comment: I edited it a bit.. hope its more clear.

Comment: Still clear as mud, I'm afraid. What are you trying to achieve? What kinds of objects are you rotating, and why? Is this a game? (It's generally best to describe your actual problem rather than trying to abstract it for us—because if you're having trouble solving the problem, you're probably also going to have trouble abstracting it.)

Comment: @Jason: You really need to address some of the questions that I asked. Your question is completely unclear, and I think a lot of stems from using words that have a precise meaning in imprecise ways.

Answer (score 0):

if i took the sentence

**Imagine two start points and end points... two seperate lines, both with the same rate of change.**

since both lines is having same rate of change so

1-  dy1/dx1 = dy2/dx2 ------------> both lines are having same slop

2-  so applying slop formula by points

```
P1 (Point)  ===> (X1,Y1)  , P1' ====>(X2,Y2)
P2 (Point ) ===> (X3,Y3) , P2' ====>(X4,Y4)
```

so    (Y2-Y1) / (X2-X1) =  (Y4-Y3) / (X4-X3)

i think , this will give you the formula , you need to put x1,y1,x2,y2,x3,y3 and x4,y4 values respectively

Comment: sorry i'm not sure if i'm clear on your answer here... could you elaborate a bit? I only have two rotational starting points and two ending points. Velocity/rate of change is the same.